# How to print out the first character of each list, then print the next character

Tags: python, list, generator, alternate

Let's say I have a list:

```
x = ['abc', 'd', 'efgh']
```

I am trying to create a function so that its desired output would return:

```
a d e b f c g h
```

Which is essentially taking the first characters of each element and then skipping onto the next element if there is no index in that area.

Is there an alternative way of doing this w/o using itertools or the zip function?

I tried doing:

```
for i in x:
      print(i[0], i[1], i[2]....etc)
```

But that only gives me an error since the second element of the list exceeds the range.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure... Take a close look and try to understand what is going on here...

```
out = []
biggest = max(len(item) for item in x)
for i in range(biggest):
    for item in x:
        if len(item) > i:
            out.append(item[i])
```

rather than `out`, I would consider `yield` to return the items in a generator.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [`roundrobin` recipe](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#recipes) from itertools:

```
def roundrobin(*iterables):
    "roundrobin('ABC', 'D', 'EF') --> A D E B F C"
    # Recipe credited to George Sakkis
    pending = len(iterables)
    nexts = cycle(iter(it).next for it in iterables)
    while pending:
        try:
            for next in nexts:
                yield next()
        except StopIteration:
            pending -= 1
            nexts = cycle(islice(nexts, pending))
```

**Demo:**

```
>>> x = ['abc', 'd', 'efgh']
>>> from itertools import cycle, islice
>>> list(roundrobin(*x))
['a', 'd', 'e', 'b', 'f', 'c', 'g', 'h']
```

---

Another option is to use `itertools.izip_longest` and `itertools.chain.from_iterable`:

```
>>> from itertools import izip_longest, chain
>>> x = ['abc', 'd', 'efgh']
>>> sentinel = object()
>>> [y for y in chain.from_iterable(izip_longest(*x, fillvalue=sentinel)) 
                                                           if y is not sentinel]
['a', 'd', 'e', 'b', 'f', 'c', 'g', 'h']
```

Comment: I'd go with `y is not sentinel` ... Just in case `y` has a funky defined `__ne__`.  (Of course, it doesn't matter for strings, but it's a good habit to get in).

Comment: @mgilson Thanks for clearing that out, actually used `is not` in my real code but went for `!=` here because I was a bit sceptical about it. ;-)

Comment: Consider your audience :)

Comment: @beroe Yeah I know, I totally missed the *w/o using itertools or the zip function?* line in the question. :/